# How can I send the value of a DynamicResource to my custom controls C# back end?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I created a custom control:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Frame xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"          
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese" 
   x:Class="Ja.Templates.Button" 
   x:Name="this" 
   Test="{DynamicResource Test}" >
</Frame>

namespace Japanese.Templates
{
    public partial class Button : Frame
    {

        public static readonly BindableProperty TestProperty = 
           BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Test), typeof(string), typeof(Button), 
           default(string), propertyChanged: TestChanged);

        public string Test { get => (string)GetValue(TestProperty); 
                             set => SetValue(TestProperty, value); }

        private static void TestChanged(BindableObject bindable, 
           object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var x = 2;
        }
```

My problem is that when I make a change like this:

```
Application.Current.Resources["Test"] = "X";
Application.Current.Resources["Test"] = "Y";
```

Then the control is not seeing the change and when I debug it does not go to the variable x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a `DynamicResource` value will change it won't notify your control. You can read more about it purpose in the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dynamicresource-markup-extension). I would also recommend you to read about `BindableProperties` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties).

In the shared code example it is unclear what are you trying to do, however, it seems like you should replace `DynamicResource` by storing the value in a `ViewModel`.

Comment: Hi, I was using a view model but I would like the control to be notified from another page.  Could I create a property in the application in a similar way to a view model.  Something like     public partial class App : Application
    { public static string Test  and then have that notify the control or anyone listening and if so, how could I do that?

Comment: @Alan2 Static properties are not bindable in my knowledge so you cannot do the above

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try and do this in a different way and will document as another question as I am having some problems with that way also.